# Can't figure out how to do make elements paginate with next and previous buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, pagination

I'm having a problem with bootstrap 4.3's pagination. I read the documentation, but nowhere is it explained how to bind the pagination bar to an actual list with items. I'm quite new to bootstrap, and MVC, so forgive me if i'm asking a very stupid question, but i just can't figure it out. Say i have an unordered list of elements (see the code below). These elements have form fields and so on, which are a part of the form, for which the page is about. I want to list every question (it's a survey) on its own, and have next and previous buttons below it, that navigate respectively to the next and previous question (item in the list) of the survey. However, as I said i really can't figure out how to do this. Would anyone have any idea how to help with this?

Here is the view (I cut the logic behind the form fields as I recon it won't be needed for this example.

```cs
@model cq.Models.EmptySurveyViewModel

<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" })) {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Sequence, Model.Sequence)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name, new { @value = Model.Name })

        <ul>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++) {
                <li>
                    //Some fields and logic here
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> End survey</button>
    }
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/pagination/) in bootstrap is just a UI component, it doesn't do anything for you. You'll need to handle the click event yourself and show/hide the elements that you want.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your UI scenario there could be a lot of solutions, if you want to show one question time it is even not necessary to use paging item, just use standard link/button to navigate to the next/previous question.

The important part is in the backend, you should order your data so you can navigate forward/backward according to the order field.

if you will have a list of questions listed then a navigation control is required, again, you should order your items and load only the amount of items to be listed in one page.

e.g.:

```cs
// Questions are ordered by date as an example
// P is current page number
// S is page size (the number of items to be displayed in one page) 
// you should send P and S parameters to the method and get back the requested paged items.
var items = Questions.OrderBy(x => x.Date)
        .Skip((P - 1) * S)
        .Take(S)
        .ToList();
```

Additionally, any pagination control needs total number of records to render page numbers accordingly, so you need to return the total number of records as well;

```cs
var totalItems = Questions.Count();
```

*There is a lot more to consider, as search and filtering parameters, show/hide only relevant number of pages, navigate prev/next, first/last, change page size, etc..., but really I don't have much time to explain more here, for now you may refer to [this article](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/38-How_to_build_an_efficient_pagination_system), hope it helps :)*